# Fetching Cart info for an existing user using Magento SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

How do I get the cart details of an existing user using Magento SOAP API?

I have an e-commerce Application based on Magento. There is already a desktop webpage for this e-commerce application. My use case is this -

-> User logs in from desktop webpage and then adds an item to the cart -> User now logs in with the same credential from mobile

I want to be able to show the item that is being added from the desktop page. But right now I don't see any SOAP API which helps me query any existing cart info for a user.

Note: I am trying this from an Android Application. So please suggest anything that I can with the SOAP API's

Comment: I guess the "Persistent Shopping Cart" functionallity suits your problem, at least for the desktop+mobile use cases. Did you already have a look at it?

Comment: I am not aware of the persistent shopping cart model. Can you please throw some pointers or link on the same

Comment: Hi Anna thanks. Took some time and googled the persistent cart model and it did help..

Comment: Hi Dibzmania, is your question solved then?

Comment: My problem had two parts  - First part was persisting the shopping cart and second part was querying the data from the persisted cart. Your solution solves the first part (Thanks for that !!) but the second part is not solved and from the comments given by other guys looks like there is no way other than extending the core API

Comment: It makes sense to update your question and put the second part of your question as a seperate one. This makes it easier to keep this platform clean, answer your problem and finally accept an answer als solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method to return the alredy existing shopping cart via SOAP API.

To share shopping carts via multiple devices, have a look at the **persistent shopping cart** functionallity which was introduced in Magento 1.6. With this you can share the shopping cart between your desktop page and mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

- [Magento API - SOAP - Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42432/fetching-cart-info-for-an-existing-user-using-magento-soap-api)
- [Magento API - SOAP -Shopping Cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.list.html)

You may need to [Creating a Custom API or Extending the Core API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html) that will get the customer quote id

Comment: I looked through the existing SOAP API but could not find any API which gives back the cart API based on the cart id. I feel this is a very basic use case. Are you sure I have to extend the core API,which means server side changes :(

Comment: Create an api that which take a customer id and return there cart id

Comment: That seems to be the fallback in case there is no other solution. Just  a question - Is a cart created for an user persisted for all times or is there any case when the cart would be removed.  Note : There is a remove cart API but my question is more like whether magento would do it automatically

Comment: Quote never get deleted (unless item is disable, out of stock or converted to order)